# Variable of Solution Directory (or something close) in TFS 2010 Build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am running a Invoke Command at the end of my build.  I am trying to get it to run a batch file.

But I don't want to hard code the path to the batch file (in case I move my build to a different build server).

I need a variable to put in for the WorkingDirectory of IvokeProcess.  In TFS 2008 Build I would have used `$(SolutionDir)`.  But I can't find anything like that in TFS 2010 Build.  (I tried Environment.CurrentDirectory and I got C:\Windows\System32

What can I do to get a reference to the path that my solution (or project) is in.

[image: Image of InvokeProcess]

Comment: I am using `$(SolutionDir)` in post build event and is it working fine. What is the specific error you are getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise against focusing on the 'Working Directory' for the type of task you 're trying to accomplish.

You can open your build process template & add a new Argument (type = string, Direction = In), with default value equaling the current full path to your batch file.

Then set this in argument in your InvokeProcess activity. Here is how I invoke NCover:
[image]

In the default value I have simply set "C:\Program Files\NCover\NCover.Console.exe"

Now each build definition has an additional parameter (under 'Process'), with default value the one that currently makes sense.

Should we move to another build server, I would have to simply update the build definitions.

Comment: I went this way.  But I don't like it, because the batch file is checked into source code.  Seems pointless to make a path to it be supplied by the creator of the Build Definition when I download it every time from TFS.