# Retrieving path to solution(s)?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We are currently setting up Team Build 2010 for our company, and I am trying to use workflow activities to retrieve the exact local path to the current solution being built. I haven't found a way to get this value, does anybody know how (without writing a custom activity)?

Either one of server or local path would suffice (i.e `$/TeamProject/Branch/OurProject` or `C:\TeamBuild\src\path\to\branch\OurProject`) since we can use the conversion activities on the server item.

The reason we need this path is for updating version info files, and that needs to be done for only the current solution being built, and the files have the same names (AssemblyInfo.cs, for example).

In this [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7179564/variable-of-solution-directory-or-something-close-in-tfs-2010-build), the solution is to define a parameter, but since this information is particular to the solution being built and not some external path, we were hoping that this info would retrievable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve this particular info without adding anything. If you navigate within your Build Process Template to the position where MSBuild breaks out, you will see that the solution that shall be build is set as a string named `localProject`. 
This will contain the local path where TFS has downloaded your SLN, something like `C:\TeamBuild\src\path\to\branch\OurProject\OurProject.sln`.
Open the XAML and navigate to:

```
Run On Agent
  Try Compile, Test, and Associate Changesets and Work Items
    Compile, Test, and Associate Changesets and Work Items
      Try Compile and Test
        Compile and Test
          For Each Configuration in BuildSettings.PlatformConfigurations
            Compile and Test for Configuration
              If BuildSettings.HasProjectsToBuild
                For Each Project in BuildSettings.ProjectsToBuild
                  Try to Compile the Project
                    Compile the Project
                      Run MSBuild for Project
```

if you select `Run MSBuild for Project` & hit `F4` you see it.

In order to retrieve what you are after you can define another string-variable `solutionPath` in your Build Process Template & insert under the `Run MSBuild for Project` a new `Assign` activity with
`To : solutionPath` and
`Value : Path.GetDirectoryName(localProject)`

Comment: Actually, I found the information I needed in a different way: each working folder can be retrieved from `Workspace.Folders` (with the property `LocalItem` for each respective item in the list) - and that was necessary for me since I needed the information prior to building. But this info proved very useful to me for a similar problem (defining test assemblies for NUnit testing).

Comment: Note that this approach fails if you are building a project, not a solution. The `localProject` variable will be set to the path to the project file (e.g. *.csproj), not the solution file in this scenario.

Comment: in TFS 2012 I used "SourcesDirectory", which when iterating through the list of projects to compile, it'll show the folder for that entry.
I only had a SLN in the projects to compile list, and the SourcesDirectory attribute helped when trying an "InvokeProcess nuger restore" activity

Answer (score 2):

1. Have you looked at the [TFS Community Build Extensions](http://tfsbuildextensions.codeplex.com/documentation), they give you a assembly versioning out of the box?
2. You can use the variable called `SourcesDirectory` to get the current Source Directory on the Build Server. You can also use an `ConvertWorkspaceItem` activity to convert  between server and local paths.

There's also a blog post that cover's all of this [here](http://www.richard-banks.org/2010/07/how-to-versioning-builds-with-tfs-2010.html).

Comment: Yes, we use TFS Community Build Extensions, it is that assembly version activity we want to use.

Our problem is that `SourcesDirectory` points to a root above a directory structure where we only want to set version on a part of, i.e. `$(SourcesDirectory)\branch\Dir1` `$(SourcesDirectory)\branch\Dir2` but not `$(SourcesDirectory)\branch\Dir3`. And `branch`can of course be different, depending on build definition.

The directory structure doesn't really follow our current solution structure because it has evolved for some time, something we should fix but can't at the moment.

Comment: In the expression use `Path.Combine` to concat paths together or other `Path` functions to spilt it up.

Comment: Yes, but I haven't found out how to retrieve the "second part". To be more specific, there ought to be some way to get the defined Workspace path(s) from the Build Definition. But I haven't found a way to dig that deep into the properties.