# How to set working directory to current workspace?

Tags: tfs

I am using TFS 2010. In the build process template, I add a new workflow activity InvokeProcess to run a batch file. I need to set the working directory of this InvokeProcess to the workspace directory of the Build agent. Is there any way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I follow this answer and get it resolved: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9564712/3918598

Basically, you will need to create a new local variable `SourcesPath` at the outter most scope and then consume it wherever you want. Do not name it `SourcesDirectory` because that name has already been used by some inner activities.

Answer (score 1):

Should be able to use workspace object. Just type workspace and intelisense will kick in. This is built in object that holds the path to the build workspace. Others available are sourcesdirectory and binariesdirectory.  Spelling maybe wrong not in front of a pc

Comment: There is no object. There is a class named `Workspace` though. But, again, no static properties to use: http://screencast.com/t/vP2SnKxLRlu6

Comment: Have a look under builddetails

Comment: The `BuildDetail` property is available. But intellisense fails to pickup its type. http://screencast.com/t/bfvrcVjf Could you please share the syntax to extract `SourceDirectory` from `BuildDetail`?

Comment: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Extensions.WellKnownEnvironmentVariables.SourcesDirectory is the 2013 way of getting it. SourcesDirectory should be available in 2010?